# How to get Input Button name?

Tags: unity-game-engine

How can I access the button name that is selected for the current Input?

Lets say that I have:

```
Input
    Name:Action
    Positive Button: A
```

How can I access the `A`? For something like:

`"Press the (button asigned by the user, in this case A) to continue"`

Instead of

`"Press the action button to continue"`

Answer (score 0):

Please put more information in your question(code)

Well, may be this could fulfill your requirement.

```
("Press the {0} to continue",this.name) // it will show the name of button pressed.
```

Comment: You can also do  Debug.Log("Press the " + stringButtonName + " to continue").

Comment: I want to tell the user to press the "Action" button but instead of showing the word Action I want to show the button assigned to that input. Lets say that the user selected the 'C' as the action button, then I want to show `"Press the C button to continue"`